# Center Google Form with CSS

Tags: html, css, google-forms

I embedded a google form on my site, which is wrapped inside a div. I try to center it with CSS, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to accomplish this task?

My code:

```css
#googleForm {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="googleForm"> 
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms....></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add `text-align: center` to element with id `googleForm`. Also you can safely remove `margin-left` and `margin-right`:

```css
#googleForm {
  /*margin-left: auto;/*
  /*margin-right: auto;*/
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="googleForm">
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms....></iframe>
</div>
```

If you want to use `margin: 0 auto` you have to set the width of the element:

```css
#googleForm {
  width: 304px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="googleForm">
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms....></iframe>
</div>
```